# Generic store of callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I need some store where I can register some callback for automatically update.

```
class Store
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<dynamic>> _callbacks = new Dictionary<Type, Action<dynamic>>();

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> updateCallback)
    {
        _callbacks.Add(typeof(T), value => updateCallback(value));
    }

    public void Save<T>(T value)
    {
        _callbacks[typeof(T)](value);
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static string _stringField = "0";
    private static int _intField = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var store = new Store();
        store.Register<string>(value => _stringField = value);
        store.Register<int>(value => _intField = value);
        Console.WriteLine($"{_stringField}/{_intField}");
        store.Save("5");
        Console.WriteLine($"{_stringField}/{_intField}");
        store.Save(7);
        Console.WriteLine($"{_stringField}/{_intField}");
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0/0 5/0 5/7

It works fine. I just don't like `Action<dynamic>` in Dictionary. Firstly it looks as a hack. Secondary it produces `box` operation in Save method, because of `dynamic`. I understand that I can't use only generics because I'm not in static context but I'm looking for a best solution for this sample. Please advise some code without changing of `Program` class. So I need to register something one time and it will be updated automatically each time of `Save` method call.

Comment: It kind of looks to me like you're reinventing the Mediatr library.  Maybe give that a peek and see if it helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will take a look on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **Delegate**, so `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` is good enough

   ```
       Delegate d = _callbacks[typeof(T)];
       Action<T> action = (Action < T >)d;
   ```
2. Storing
   delegates in collections is normal practice (not a hack)
3. Boxing to object is imperfect practice

Comment: Added. But can I say that if you are doing messages routing based on the type - it is a task for conditional operator `if` ?

Comment: Type is additional info. In the real code it contains some identifiers and of course there are some `if`s

Comment: If you construct something like parsing function run-time to a specific class properties: use Expressions and its compile option. This way you can construct method that has no type casts at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like `dynamic`, you can store your callbacks as `Action<object>`, like this:

```
class Store {
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> _callbacks = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> updateCallback) {
                                                          // cast here
        _callbacks.Add(typeof(T), value => updateCallback((T) value));
    }

    public void Save<T>(T value) {
        _callbacks[typeof(T)](value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit? It still produces box, isn't it?

Comment: I feel there is no sufficient benefit. It looks as it just requires to add another one cast operation.

Comment: @Serg046 but dynamic is not free either. It uses reflection under the hood, so I don't think one cast is worse than that.